# Do user controls need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls, inotifypropertychanged

In ASP.NET Web Forms, do user controls need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to let web pages use them in model binding context properly, like this:

```
<uc1:MyControl runat="server" SomeProperty=<%# Item.Age%> ID="MC1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they do not, they need to inherit from Control or WebControl though as far as I know. It's been a while since I wrote any controls.

**EDIT:**

Checkout 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zt27tfhy(v=vs.100).aspx

and specifically
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4s70936s(v=vs.100).aspx

And if you use object browser in Visual Studio you can see what existing controls implement, for example TextBox implements:

```
IEditableTextControl
IPostBackDataHandler
ITextControl
WebControl
```

and WebControl implements

```
Control
IAttributeAccessor
```

etc etc... and nothing in any Interfaces or BaseTypes include INotifyPropertyChanged.
IF you're coming from a Windows Metro/Phone dev background then I can see why you might think so as it's used a lot there.

Hope this helps

Comment: Any reference that could confirm this claim?

Comment: That's some valuable contribution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely say they are not "needed", however the ComponentModel's `INotifyPropertyChanged` is very generic and could be used on an ASP.NET Web Form's user control.  I think the best situation in which this would warrant using `INotifyPropertyChanged` is if you're having to write a bunch of events to let your user control's client know when several properties change.  The `INotifyPropertyChanged` event / pattern is much simpler than having a property changed event for each property you need to notify the client about.

All of that being said, I've mainly seen `INotifyPropertyChanged`used in DataContexts for ORM's and for binding in WPF.  These seem to be the more popular usages for this model.  I don't think I've ever seen an ASP.NET Web Form control use INotifyPropertyChanged, but that's not to say that it wouldn't ever be useful.

I have generally found that the major events needed for an ASP.NET Web Forms user control are more along the lines of feedback from the user such as "user clicked this button" or "user made this selection".  Because of the nature of the web and the client having to "postback" their data, most clients of your ASP.NET Web Forms user control are going to inspect each property of the control that it needs whenever your control raises a "user did something" event.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It strengthens my belief! :)